# How to add a tick sign on a folder in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, wxpython

i am developing a small application in windows using python and i am new to this. I want to show a tick sign on a folder. How can I achieve that? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to an overlay like what some source control applications do? Which widget are you expecting this to happen in?

Comment: Could you provide more information?

Comment: i am using python for this app. i want to show an tick sign on folder like dropbox do.